# What does blue color mean in Intellij IDEA Inspections settings?

Tags: intellij-idea, inspection

In Settings > Editor > Inspections there is a list of all inspections.

Some of inspections are listed in a blue font color.

What does blue color mean in this context?

[image: screenshot of Settings dialog with Editor-Inspections section selected]

(my own highlights in red)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It highlights the inspections that differ from the default profile (enabled vs disabled or vice versa, or inspection settings were changed).

Comment: Is this information available on any of the Jetbrains' help pages?

Comment: I don't think it's available, but it's pretty obvious after you change an inspection. I'll ask the document writers to add it to the product documentation.